# Convert JSON string to array of JSON objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to convert this string

```
{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test2"}
```

to array of 2 JSON objects. How should I do it?

best

Comment: If you get this as a JSON string, then it is not valid JSON anyway... where do you get it from? Could you post a more complete code example?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
var str = '{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test2"}';
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON('[' + str + ']');
```

`jsonObj` is your JSON object.

Comment: jQuery.parseJSON() has been deprecated.

Comment: @MarcL. What should replace it?

Comment: @Parapluie [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/json/parse) has been part of the "standard built-in" objects for several years now.

Answer (score 40):

As simple as that.

```
var str = '{"id":1,"name":"Test1"},{"id":2,"name":"Test2"}';
 dataObj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: As the comment on the original question states, the string as given is not valid JSON.

Comment: In some cases (like mine) you might find a trailing comma at the end of the string causes some issues. This method will still work - you just need to remove that last comma using regex first: str = str.replace(/,\s*$/, "");

Answer (score 33):

As Luca indicated, add extra `[]` to your string and use the code below:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

to test it you can use the snippet below.

```
var s =" [{'id':1,'name':'Test1'},{'id':2,'name':'Test2'}]";
var myObject = eval('(' + s + ')');
for (i in myObject)
{
   alert(myObject[i]["name"]);
}
```

hope it helps..

Comment: “eval is Evil: The eval function is the most misused feature of JavaScript. Avoid it” - Douglas Crockford in "Javascript: The Good Parts"
Eval is not recommended due to how dangerous it can be. It's better to use JSON.parse() instead.

Comment: Thanks a ton after lots of research I ended up with eval function!! which transformed my stringed JSON to actual array type JSON data

Answer (score 7):

Append extra an `[` and `]` to the beginning and end of the string. This will make it an array. Then use `eval()` or some safe JSON serializer to serialize the string and make it a real JavaScript datatype.

You should use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js instead of `eval()`. eval is only if you're doing some quick debugging/testing.

Answer (score 5):

If your using jQuery, it's [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function can be used and is preferable to JavaScript's native `eval()` function.

Answer (score 2):

I know a lot of people are saying use eval.  the eval() js function will call the compiler, and that can offer a series of security risks.  It is best to avoid its usage where possible.  The parse function offers a more secure alternative.