# parsing JSON to javascript array

Tags: json, jquery

I get this JSON response from my service call :

```
[Object { __type="TestDTO:#TestServer.Data", DateCreated="/Date(1298357607157+0500)/", more...}, Object { __type="TestDTO:#TestServer.Data", DateCreated="/Date(1298357628953+0500)/", more...}]
```

and I want to use Jquery templates which require a javascript array

like :

```
var books = [
            { title: "ASP.NET 4 Unleashed", price: 37.79, picture: "AspNet4.jpg" },
            { title: "ASP.NET MVC Unleashed", price: 44.99, picture: "AspNetMshed.jpg" },
            { title: "ASP.NET Kick Start", price: 4.00, picture: "AspNetKickStart.jpg" },
            { title: "ASP.NET MVC Unleashed iPhone", price: 44.99, picture: "Asele.jpg" },
            ];
```

How can I convert the JSSON response to below format( please ignore the data) just format should be same.

I am using this in ajax success method:

```
 success: function (response) {
                    var tr = response.d;
                    var tests = tr.Tests;
                      $("#TestsTemplate").tmpl(tests).appendTo("#divTests");
```

`.tmpl(tests)` requires javascript array

Mu Jquery template looks like this :

#### Test Name: ${TestName}

Test Page:  ${TestPage}
                    ID: ${ID}
                    Date Created: ${DateCreated}
                    Result:  ${Result}
                    Status: ${Status}

```
                <div id="divTests">

                </div>
```

and what I get from json is a DTO  below

public class TestRunDTO
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string TestSuiteName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public int Result { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public List Tests { get; set; }
    }

I want to show this test collection in TestRunDTO using jquery templates

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375537/convert-json-string-to-array-of-json-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the returned JSON to some other object expected by `$.tmpl`. Use something like this:

```
/*
 * returnedObject - data returned by your service call
 */

var returnArr = [];
$.each(returnedObject, function() {
    var _tmp = {};
    _tmp.title = this.title;
    _tmp.price = this.price;
    _tmp.picture = this.picture;
    returnArr.push(_tmp);
});

$.('#template').tmpl(returnArr);
```

Hope this helps.