# convert json array to javascript array

Tags: javascript, json

i have a json array that i want to convert into a plain javascript array:

This is my json array:

```
var users = {"0":"John","1":"Simon","2":"Randy"}
```

How to convert it into a plain javascript array like this:

```
var users = ["John", "Simon", "Randy"]
```

Comment: I also found this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375537/convert-json-string-to-array-of-json-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Can any tell me this is json array or json object?

Comment: @anil This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12289961/386579

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`users` is already a JS object (not JSON). But here you go:

```
var users_array = [];
for(var i in users) {
    if(users.hasOwnProperty(i) && !isNaN(+i)) {
        users_array[+i] = users[i];
    }
}
```

***Edit:*** Insert elements at correct position in array. Thanks [@RoToRa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318493/rotora).

Maybe it is easier to not create this kind of object in the first place. How is it created?

Comment: This json array is created dynamically with Zend_Json::encode, but the response is passed back to a js function, that accepts a plain javascript array.

Comment: @dskanth: If you are not doing anything fancy, use the native function `json_encode`. It will only turn associative arrays into JSON objects and numerical indexed ones into arrays.

Comment: Careful, your code may not assign the values to the correct indexes, because you are assuming the object properties are iterated sorted. `if (!isNaN(+i)) {users_array[+i] = users[i]}` may be better.

Comment: @RoToRa: You are right. No I did not assume that they are sorted, but I didn't pay attention to the order... I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun - if you know the length of the array, then the following will work ([and seems to be faster](http://jsperf.com/convert-object-to-array/2)):

```
users.length = 3;
users = Array.prototype.slice.call(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a Jquery+Javascript solution, for those who are interested:

```
var user_list = [];

$.each( users, function( key, value ) {
    user_list.push( value );    
});

console.log(user_list);
```