# Save a json in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, variables

I'm trying to save a json in a javascript array but I don't understand how to do it. I don't want to save all the content in the first element of the array.
That's my function:

```
function jeyson()
{
var onion = new XMLHttpRequest();
onion.open("GET", "json.json", true);
onion.send(null);

/* var anotheronion = angular.fromJson(onion.responseText, false); */

    var onionarray = new Array()

}
```

onionarray is the array that I'd like to contain my json file.

My json could be something like:

```
{

"count": 2,
"e": 1,
"k": null,
"privateresult": 0,
"q": "surname",
"start": 0,
"cards": [
    {
        "__guid__": "efd192abc3063737b05a09a311df0ea0",
        "company": false,
        "__title__": "name1 surname",
        "__class__": "entity",
        "services": false,
        "__own__": false,
        "vanity_urls": [
            "name1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "__guid__": "01917cfa71a23df0a67a4a122835aba8",
        "photo": {
            "__own__": false,
            "__title__": null,
            "__class__": "image",
            "__guid__": "01917cfa71a23df04d03f83cb08c11e1"
        },
        "company": false,
        "__title__": "name2 surname",
        "__class__": "entity",
        "services": false,
        "__own__": false,
        "vanity_urls": [
            "name2"
        ]
    }
]

}
```

How can I save it in my array?

PS I don't have problems like "same origin policy" because the json file is on the same server (for now I'm working with local files. Could I work with files that are not on the same domain?).

**PS**
Is it possible to use json as a javascript object (like an array)? If I want to search something in my json object how can I do it?

```
function geisson()
{
var iabile = new XMLHttpRequest();
iabile.open("GET", "json.json", true);
iabile.send(null);

var objectjson = {};
objectson = JSON.parse(iabile.responseText);
alert(objectson.cards.toSource());  
return false;
}
```

Comment: Possible dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618548/convert-json-array-to-javascript-array

Comment: sorry if the way is not that pretty but I'm a beginner :D

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Remember to upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And choose/select the best answer to your own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your incoming JSON is not an array; it is a JSON structure (in Javascript, the same as an object). So it can not be directly stored as an array.

The json does include an array as the `cards` element. -- Do want that?

You need to

1. Parse the incoming JSON into a JS structure. (Use JSON.parse.)
2. Once you have the structure in Javascript:

   ```
   incoming = JSON.parse(data);
   onionarray = incoming.cards;
   ```

Also note that the modern way to declare an empty array is

```
var onionarray = [];  

// not
var onionarray = new Array()
```

Answer (score 1):

use the browser methods `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` to convert your json to a javascript object and back.

In your case, `onionarray` should not be an array but rather an object (In fact arrays and objects are >pretty< similar in javascript). You can assign your jsondata like that:

```
onionarray = JSON.parse(data);
```