# How to create JSONObject and JSON ARRAy from json string in android?

Tags: android, json

My String contains json

```
result=[{"USER_ID":83,"PROJECT_BY_DETAILS":"An adaptation of a nursery rhyme into a dramatic film"},{"USER_ID":88,"PROJECT_BY_DETAILS":"Test - over ye mountain blue "}]
```

How to create JSONOBject and JSONarray from this string

I used this code

```
JSONObject json =new JSONObject(result);
            //Get the element that holds the earthquakes ( JSONArray )
            JSONArray earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("");
```

i got error

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"USER_ID":83,"PRO
```

Answer (score 0):

If it starts with [ its an array, try with:

JSONArray json =new JSONArray(result);

[Difference between JSONObject and JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289844/difference-between-jsonobject-and-jsonarray)

Answer (score 0):

use  [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for you to do that.

That Json response is an array you know it because of the square brackets [].

1. Create a mapping object (a java class) with field USER_ID and PROJECT_BY_DETAILS.

   public class yourClass(){
       public String USER_ID;
       public String PROJECT_BY_DETAILS;
   }
2. Create a Type array like so.

   final Type typeYourObject = new TypeToken>(){}.getType();
3. define your list private

   List yourList;
4. Using Gson you will convert that array to a List like so

   yourList = gson.fromJson(yourJson, typeYourObject);
5. with that list later you can do whatever you want. Also with Gson convert it back to JsonArray or create a customs JsonObject.

Comment: That is all you need. I explain it. The only thing I miss was the instantiation of Gson. like Gson gson = new Gson();

Answer (score 0):

use this code for your JsonArray:

```
try {
                        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(YOUR_JSON_STRING);
                         for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonDATA = json.getJSONObject(i);

                            String jsonid = jsonDATA.getInt("USER_ID");
                            String jsondetails = jsonDATA.getString("PROJECT_BY_DETAILS");
                            }
                             } catch (JSONException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding the JSON object looks like this,

`{
  "RESULT":[
             {
                "USER_ID":83,
                "PROJECT_BY_DETAILS":"An adaptation of a nursery rhyme into a dramatic film"
             },
             {
                "USER_ID":88,
                "PROJECT_BY_DETAILS":"Test - over ye mountain blue "
             }
           ]
}`

You are converting this to a String and you wish to re-construct the JSON object. The decode function in the android-side would be this,

`void jsonDecode(String jsonResponse)
{
    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        JSONArray jData = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("RESULT");
        for(int i = 0; i < jData.length(); ++i)
        {
           JSONObject jObj = jData.getJSONObject(i);
           String userID = jObj.optString("USER_ID");
           String projectDetails = jObj.optString("PROJECT_BY_DETAILS");
           Toast.makeText(context, userID + " -- " + projectDetails,0).show(); 
        } 
     }
     catch(JSONException e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}`