# Validate GET JSON response for login screen and go to home screen

Tags: android, json, android-intent, http-post, getjson

When user login to the app I am getting JSON response with username, pasword, token, userID and onboarding. As per the requirement of the application I hava to redirect the user to home page if this onboarding value is "true" in the JSON data.

```
[
    {
    "display_name": "my email ID",
    "msg_status": "success",
    "userid": "userID",
    "plan_type": "none",
    "token": "my token",
    "requires_onboarding": true
    }
]
```

I get all these fields in my java code. Now I want to let user go to the home screen if this onboarding value is true.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get this json as a String, parse it like the following code. IF you are already with a JSONArray, then you won't need to use the first line.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
JSONObject json2 = jsonArray.get(0);
boolean onBoarding = json2.getBoolean("requires_onboarding");
```

Then you can do whatever you want with your boolean variable.

---

If you have questions about JSON, here's a little information about it:

JSONArray is something like: `events:[ {"object1": value}, {"object1":Value} ]`
Which means that you get the JSONArray and use `jsonArray.get(position)` for each thing inside it. (Note that you can have JSONArrays inside JSONArrays.

JSONObject is basically the "string" name with a value attached.

So you'll always have to see how the data you're getting is structured to parse right and choose correctly between JSONObjects or Arrays.

[Here is a complete explanation the difference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289844/difference-between-jsonobject-and-jsonarray)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this:

```
boolean what = false;
try{
  JSONArray mRootArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
  JSONObject jInnerObject = mRootArray.getJSONObject(0);
  what = jInnerObject.getBoolean("requires_onboarding");
 }catch(Exception e){
  what = false;
  e.printstacktrace();
 }
```

Now maintain as per state of boolean:

```
if(what){
// Go to netxt screen
}else{
// Stay here
}
```

Hope this will help you,

Answer (score 1):

I got the required output guys thank you for your response it is as I mentioned below.

```
    String name = list.get(5);
    if (name.equals("true"))
    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, OnBoardingOne.class));
```