# Value [] of type org.json.JSONarray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json

I have an error as stated in the title when trying to read SQL and encode it back to android.

I have tried the following:

1. Verified the value of $androidIMEI by printing to log file, value is returned as expected.
2. Verified the output of $sql and the query is OK (including the $_POST['myIMEI_toString']) value from android.
3. Verified the value of $json array, 2 arrays are returned as the query returns 2 rows from SQL, OK.
4. Replacing

   ```
   $androidIMEI = isset($_POST['myIMEI_toString']) ? $_POST['myIMEI_toString'] : '';
   ```

   WITH

   ```
   $androidIMEI = "000000000000000" //works fine but I want to get that programmatically.
   ```

Code:

1. Android (Send IMEI):

   ```
   TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
   myIMEI = mngr.getDeviceId();

   myIMEI_toString = myIMEI.toString();
   ```

   ...............

   ```
   protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

                 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();         

               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myIMEI_toString",myIMEI_toString));

                   try
                   {
                   HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://path_on_server/file.php");
                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                   is = entity.getContent();
                   InputStreamReader ireader = new InputStreamReader(is);
                   BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(ireader);
                   sb = new StringBuilder();
                   String line = null;
                   while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                       sb.append(line);
                   }
                   Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");


               }
                   catch(Exception e)

               {
                   System.out.println("Error catch");

               }
                   return id;     

           }
   ```
2. Android (JSON):

   ```
         try {
      JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
      JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("myarray");
      for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
       name = jsonChildNode.getString("Request_Name");
       number = jsonChildNode.getString("Request_Number");
       username = jsonChildNode.getString("Request_Username");
       status = jsonChildNode.getString("Status");

       arrName.add(name);
       arrNumber.add(number);
       arrUsername.add(username);
       arrStatus.add(status);

       System.out.println("Name: "+name);
       System.out.println("Number: "+number);
       System.out.println("Username: "+username);
       System.out.println("Status: "+status);

      }
     } catch (JSONException e) {

         Log.i("Error Log: ", e.toString());
         System.out.println("Error: "+e.toString());


         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
   ```
3. PHP:

   ```
   <?php

   include 'config.php';

   //$androidIMEI = "000000000000000";
   $androidIMEI = isset($_POST['myIMEI_toString']) ? $_POST['myIMEI_toString'] : '';

       //$f = fopen("log.txt", "w");
       //fwrite($f, print_r($androidIMEI, true));
       //fclose($f); 

   $con=mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
   mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");

   $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE Request='0' AND IMEI = '$androidIMEI' "; 
   $result = mysql_query($sql);

   $json = array(); 
   if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
       while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
       $json['myarray'][]=$row;
       }

   }
   else
   {
       //$error =  "Error selecting record: " . $conn->error " ";
       //$f = fopen("$error.txt", "w");
       //fwrite($f, print_r($error, true));
       //fclose($f); 
   }

       $f = fopen("log.txt", "w");
       fwrite($f, print_r($sql, true));
       fclose($f); 

   mysql_close($con);
   echo json_encode($json); 
   ?>
   ```
4. Logcat Error:

   ```
   org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONarray cannot be converted to JSONObject
   ```

(i have asked this question before but will try again with more information)

Comment: Doesn't it tell you what line the error is on?

Comment: You are returning an array parsed in JSON (JSONarray) and you are expecting a JSONObject.
Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289844/difference-between-jsonobject-and-jsonarray