# Android Studio error: org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to get JSON data from an api which generates the user name and password but I am failing to do so, please help
[image: Postman output]

[image: Android Studio function andLogcat]

Comment: Please add your code as text and not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API returns JSON Object instead of JSONArray. Parse your response directly in JSONObject instead of JSONArray and retrieve id and password from it.

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);
String id=jsonObject.getString("u_name");
String passworf=jsonObject.getString("u_pass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API returns JSON Object instead of JSONArray.

Check difference between those two :
[JSON Object vs JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289844/difference-between-jsonobject-and-jsonarray)

Though you can work with JSONObject too, just do below:

```
String value =  jsonObject.getString("key")
```

In case of you are using Volley, then by default Volley returns success response by parsing it in JSONObject. So `jsonObject` would be replaced by `response`.