# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT error with gson, android, retrofit

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

Hi I am trying to get data from the API and I am getting the next error:

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

The data that I am getting is the following:

```
 "code": "01",
    "data": {
        "code": "0",
        "time": "14-05-2019 16:22:28.661",
        "data": [
            {
                "geometry": {
                    "BoundingBox": null,
                    "ExtraMembers": null,
                    "Type": 7,
                    "Coordinates": {
                        "Latitude": 40.401609,
                        "Values": [
                            -3.674735,
                            40.401609
                        ],
                        "Longitude": -3.674735
                    },
                    "CoordinateReferenceSystem": null
                }
            },
            {
                "geometry": {
                    "BoundingBox": null,
                    ....
```

And the pojo for get this data is the next:

```
public class ApiResponse<T extends ApiResponseData> {
    ...   
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<T> data;
    ...
}

public class DData implements ApiResponseData {
...
```

And the retrofit call for get data is the next:

```
public void getListOfDs(final MutableLiveData<ApiResponse<DData>> data) {
        Call<ApiResponse<DData>> call = CApiInterface.getListOfDs(ID_CLIENT);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse<DData>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse<DData>> call, Response<ApiResponse<DData>> response) {
                ApiResponse<DData> apiResponse = response.body();
                data.setValue(apiResponse);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse<DData>> call, Throwable t) {
                data.setValue(createFailedResponse());
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
```

The question is why am I getting this error, in the `ApiResponse` I have a List in this case List and I am getting a list of `DData`, for another case like the response is only a single `DData` this work perfectly any idea?

Any idea that how can solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Data" key is twice, one in top is of object type but it should be of type list/Array. Your response should with in brackets[]
currently {} represents Json Object, not list.

Refer this to understand difference between JSONArray and JSONObject
[Difference between JSONObject and JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289844/difference-between-jsonobject-and-jsonarray)

Comment: My response in data, that is the problem is a list  of objects `"data": [
            {`

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES I just updated it. "data" key is twice. First one is of JsonObject

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to deserialize the data object as a List but the first "data" in the hierarchy is an object, what causes the exception. 
You need to review your Pojo class to fit the Json structure.

Maybe something like this can work:

```
public class ApiResponse<T extends ApiResponseData> {
    ...
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private Data<T> data;
    ...
}

public class Data<T extends ApiResponseData>  {

    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    private String code;

    @SerializedName("time")
    @Expose
    private String time;

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<T> data;

    ...
}
```

Comment: But "data" is a list of object  `"data": [{`

Comment: There is two "data" in the json