# Parse Json file in python and print response in dialogflow

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file. I want to parse it and print the response in Dialogflow.

```
import json
```

#### some JSON:

```
    x = '{
          "first": {"Id": "1","Zone": "South", "Product": "toy"}, 
          "second": {"Id": "2","Zone": "North", "Product": "softtoy"}, 
          "third": {"Id": "1", "Zone": "East","Product": "bat"}
         }'
```

#### parse x:

```
y = json.loads(x)
```

Comment: Just to let you know one thing - the `i` (index of the for-loop) is not an integer. It is the key of the json. In your case it is "1" not the index 1. That's why I used "first" and "second" words in my answer.

Comment: I am new to python & json, so it is difficult to understand at first. If there is any link which explains loop in json file well

Comment: Trust me. I am doing Python for the first time. I am a java / j2ee developer. You can check my profile :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    import json

    # some JSON:
    x = '{"first": {"Id": "1","Zone": "South", "Product": "toy"}, "second": {"Id": "2","Zone": "North", "Product": "softtoy"}, "third": {"Id": "1", "Zone": "East","Product": "bat"}}'

    # parse x:
    y = json.loads(x)

    # Get the key `Zone` under `1`
    z = y['1']['Zone']
    print(z)


    if z == 'South':
        print('Yes')
```

**Output:**
South
Yes

---

**Update : 1** 
Your json is an object. It is not array. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38561016/2086966

So, ***you does not have to iterate with a for-loop***.
Just use as follows

```
if y['1']['Zone'] == 'North':
    print('No')
if y['1']['Id'] == 1:
    print('Yes')
```

---

**Update : 2**

**I guess this is the one you are searching for**

```
for i in y:
 print(i + " Id -> " +  y[i]['Id'])
 print(i + " Zone -> " +  y[i]['Zone'])
```

**Output** 
second Id -> 2
second Zone -> North
first Id -> 1
first Zone -> South

Here is the working code : https://onlinegdb.com/rJ4Ui3m0E

---

**Update : 3**

```
for i in y: 
    if y[i]['Id'] == "1": 
        if y[i]['Zone'] == "East": 
            print (y[i]['Product'])
```

**Output** 
bat
Here is the working code :  https://onlinegdb.com/rJ41KyER4

Comment: I am facing issue in using loop which will read each element and return response

Comment: This code is working. But this is not what I am looking for. I have a data set which contains lots of similar json values. I want to search if Zone = North, then it will check Product and if product does not matches then it search for other North Zone and co on. Hope you understood my problem.

Comment: Shreya, That's the logic you need to implement. As of my understanding it's just the if condition handling. Please try yourself (with my code) in the given url `https://onlinegdb.com/rJ4Ui3m0E` (click on `fork it`) and share it to me. Let's play with it. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: import json


# some JSON:
x = '{"first": {"Id": "1","Zone": "South", "Product": "toy"}, "second": {"Id": "2","Zone": "North", "Product": "softtoy"}, "third": {"Id": "1", "Zone": "East","Product": "bat"}}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)


for i in y:
 if y.Id == "1":
     if y.Zone == "East":
         print (y.Product)

Comment: Pls give me a new URL (you can fork my url) - read my above comment again. Click on `Fork this`. Edit your changes. Then click on `Share`. You will see a new URL in the share box.

Comment: You should read well before you comment. You are again making the same mistake. It's not `y.key` it is `y[i]['key']`. Please make sure not to make simple mistakes (without reading the answers). https://onlinegdb.com/rJ41KyER4

Comment: Trust me. I am doing Python for the first time. I am a java / j2ee developer. You can check my profile :)

Comment: Updated the answer with `Update 3`. Please go through. And select it as right answer (tick mark will become green color) so that it would help others to identify.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how you parsed it. Your error message shows that the variable 'i' is a string.

you can use the ['json' library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), and do something like this to parse and use your json file:

```
import json
with open(file_name) as json_file:
    file_data = json.load(json_file)
print(file_data['1']['Zone'])
```

#### Answer to your comment:

If you want to iterate over the json file with for loop, you can simply read it into an dictionary and iterate over the dictionary:

```
with open(file_name) as json_file:
    file_data = json.load(json_file)

for sub_dict_value in file_data.values():
    for key, value in sub_dict_value.items():
        print(key, value)
```

Comment: I am using below code :for i in jsonfilepath:
                if 'Zone' == 'North':
                    if 'Product' == 'Educational Loan':
                        if 'Business Segment' == 'Agricultural':
                            Y = 'Credit_RWA'
                                        'fulfillmentText': Y
                    }

Comment: @Shreya - Please update your question with this code.

Comment: @ShreyaSinha I'm not sure if the updated code answers your question. please clarify.

Comment: @WenD This is not working. I am getting error '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'values'