# Flutter: Retrieve a list of stocks Stats and quotes from IEX JSON API

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, stock, algorithmic-trading

## IEX JSON API:

```
  import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
  import 'dart:convert';
  import '../models/stocks.dart';



   Future<Map<String,dynamic>> getStocks() async {

  // final String url = 
'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch? 
  symbols=aapl,fb&types=quote&token=Hidden';
 //  final client = new http.Client();
  // final streamedRest = await client.send(
  //  http.Request('get', Uri.parse(url))


   const url = 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?s 
  ymbols=aapl,fb&types=quote&token=Hidden';
   final response = await http.get(url);
  final decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body).keys();
   final data = Stocks.fromJson(decodedResponse);

    //http.Response response = await http.get(Uri, headers: {"Accept": 
   "application/json"});
   //print(jsonDecode(response.body).keys());
     return jsonDecode(response.body).keys();
    //  return streamedRest.stream
   //   .transform(utf8.decoder)
    // .transform(json.decoder)
    // .expand((data) => (data as List<dynamic>))
   //  .map((data) => Stocks.fromJSON(data));
   }
```

> {"AAPL":{"stats":{"week52change":0.108189,"week52high":244.8,"week52low":142,"marketcap":1100781864400,"employees":132000,"day200MovingAvg":196.46,"day50MovingAvg":220.62,"float":4512324403.94,"avg10Volume":23328121.8,"avg30Volume":26924247.43,"ttmEPS":11.8267,"ttmDividendRate":2.96,"companyName":"Apple, Inc.","sharesOutstanding":4519180000,"maxChangePercent":240.1683,"year5ChangePercent":1.315,"year2ChangePercent":0.5505,"year1ChangePercent":0.108189,"ytdChangePercent":0.542427,"month6ChangePercent":0.186574,"month3ChangePercent":0.176601,"month1ChangePercent":0.102022,"day30ChangePercent":0.113509,"day5ChangePercent":0.030329,"nextDividendDate":null,"dividendYield":0.012152065029969619,"nextEarningsDate":"2019-10-30","exDividendDate":"2019-08-09","peRatio":20.75,"beta":1.534551916699308},"quote":{"symbol":"AAPL","companyName":"Apple, Inc.","primaryExchange":"NASDAQ","calculationPrice":"tops","open":null,"openTime":null,"close":null,"closeTime":null,"high":null,"low":null,"latestPrice":245.395,"latestSource":"IEX real time price","latestTime":"12:37:57

## Logs:

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
I/OpenGLRenderer( 4854): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer( 4854): Swap behavior 1
D/        ( 4854): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdc20bf00, tid 4881
D/EGL_emulation( 4854): eglCreateContext: 0xe3d47760: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 4854): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3d47760: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc6b24a30)
D/        ( 4854): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xc6b386c0, tid 4874
D/EGL_emulation( 4854): eglCreateContext: 0xdc27d780: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation( 4854): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdc27d780: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc6b24dc0)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/Choreographer( 4854): Skipped 279 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation( 4854): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3d47760: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc6b24a30)
I/OpenGLRenderer( 4854): Davey! duration=6180ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=596431275408, Vsync=601081275222, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=601083214976, AnimationStart=601083253387, PerformTraversalsStart=601083255696, DrawStart=601096302305, SyncQueued=601333900000, SyncStart=601335418694, IssueDrawCommandsStart=601335535183, SwapBuffers=602308827762, FrameCompleted=602612881859, DequeueBufferDuration=66828000, QueueBufferDuration=276000, 
D/EGL_emulation( 4854): eglMakeCurrent: 0xdc27d780: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xc6b24dc0)

## Class

```
import 'dart:convert';

Stocks stocksFromJson(String str) => Stocks.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String stocksToJson(Stocks data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Stocks {
  String symbol;
  String companyName;
  String primaryExchange;
  String calculationPrice;
  int open;
  int openTime;
  double close;
  int closeTime;
  double high;
  double low;
  double latestPrice;
  String latestSource;
  String latestTime;
  int latestUpdate;
  int latestVolume;
  dynamic iexRealtimePrice;
  dynamic iexRealtimeSize;
  dynamic iexLastUpdated;
  double delayedPrice;
  int delayedPriceTime;
  double extendedPrice;
  double extendedChange;
  double extendedChangePercent;
  int extendedPriceTime;
  double previousClose;
  int previousVolume;
  int change;
  double changePercent;
  int volume;
  dynamic iexMarketPercent;
  dynamic iexVolume;
  int avgTotalVolume;
  dynamic iexBidPrice;
  dynamic iexBidSize;
  dynamic iexAskPrice;
  dynamic iexAskSize;
  int marketCap;
  double peRatio;
  double week52High;
  int week52Low;
  double ytdChange;
  int lastTradeTime;
  bool isUsMarketOpen;

  Stocks({
    this.symbol,
    this.companyName,
    this.primaryExchange,
    this.calculationPrice,
    this.open,
    this.openTime,
    this.close,
    this.closeTime,
    this.high,
    this.low,
    this.latestPrice,
    this.latestSource,
    this.latestTime,
    this.latestUpdate,
    this.latestVolume,
    this.iexRealtimePrice,
    this.iexRealtimeSize,
    this.iexLastUpdated,
    this.delayedPrice,
    this.delayedPriceTime,
    this.extendedPrice,
    this.extendedChange,
    this.extendedChangePercent,
    this.extendedPriceTime,
    this.previousClose,
    this.previousVolume,
    this.change,
    this.changePercent,
    this.volume,
    this.iexMarketPercent,
    this.iexVolume,
    this.avgTotalVolume,
    this.iexBidPrice,
    this.iexBidSize,
    this.iexAskPrice,
    this.iexAskSize,
    this.marketCap,
    this.peRatio,
    this.week52High,
    this.week52Low,
    this.ytdChange,
    this.lastTradeTime,
    this.isUsMarketOpen,
  });

  factory Stocks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Stocks(
    symbol: json["symbol"],
    companyName: json["companyName"],
    primaryExchange: json["primaryExchange"],
    calculationPrice: json["calculationPrice"],
    open: json["open"],
    openTime: json["openTime"],
    close: json["close"].toDouble(),
    closeTime: json["closeTime"],
    high: json["high"].toDouble(),
    low: json["low"].toDouble(),
    latestPrice: json["latestPrice"].toDouble(),
    latestSource: json["latestSource"],
    latestTime: json["latestTime"],
    latestUpdate: json["latestUpdate"],
    latestVolume: json["latestVolume"],
    iexRealtimePrice: json["iexRealtimePrice"],
    iexRealtimeSize: json["iexRealtimeSize"],
    iexLastUpdated: json["iexLastUpdated"],
    delayedPrice: json["delayedPrice"].toDouble(),
    delayedPriceTime: json["delayedPriceTime"],
    extendedPrice: json["extendedPrice"].toDouble(),
    extendedChange: json["extendedChange"].toDouble(),
    extendedChangePercent: json["extendedChangePercent"].toDouble(),
    extendedPriceTime: json["extendedPriceTime"],
    previousClose: json["previousClose"].toDouble(),
    previousVolume: json["previousVolume"],
    change: json["change"],
    changePercent: json["changePercent"].toDouble(),
    volume: json["volume"],
    iexMarketPercent: json["iexMarketPercent"],
    iexVolume: json["iexVolume"],
    avgTotalVolume: json["avgTotalVolume"],
    iexBidPrice: json["iexBidPrice"],
    iexBidSize: json["iexBidSize"],
    iexAskPrice: json["iexAskPrice"],
    iexAskSize: json["iexAskSize"],
    marketCap: json["marketCap"],
    peRatio: json["peRatio"].toDouble(),
    week52High: json["week52High"].toDouble(),
    week52Low: json["week52Low"],
    ytdChange: json["ytdChange"].toDouble(),
    lastTradeTime: json["lastTradeTime"],
    isUsMarketOpen: json["isUSMarketOpen"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "symbol": symbol,
    "companyName": companyName,
    "primaryExchange": primaryExchange,
    "calculationPrice": calculationPrice,
    "open": open,
    "openTime": openTime,
    "close": close,
    "closeTime": closeTime,
    "high": high,
    "low": low,
    "latestPrice": latestPrice,
    "latestSource": latestSource,
    "latestTime": latestTime,
    "latestUpdate": latestUpdate,
    "latestVolume": latestVolume,
    "iexRealtimePrice": iexRealtimePrice,
    "iexRealtimeSize": iexRealtimeSize,
    "iexLastUpdated": iexLastUpdated,
    "delayedPrice": delayedPrice,
    "delayedPriceTime": delayedPriceTime,
    "extendedPrice": extendedPrice,
    "extendedChange": extendedChange,
    "extendedChangePercent": extendedChangePercent,
    "extendedPriceTime": extendedPriceTime,
    "previousClose": previousClose,
    "previousVolume": previousVolume,
    "change": change,
    "changePercent": changePercent,
    "volume": volume,
    "iexMarketPercent": iexMarketPercent,
    "iexVolume": iexVolume,
    "avgTotalVolume": avgTotalVolume,
    "iexBidPrice": iexBidPrice,
    "iexBidSize": iexBidSize,
    "iexAskPrice": iexAskPrice,
    "iexAskSize": iexAskSize,
    "marketCap": marketCap,
    "peRatio": peRatio,
    "week52High": week52High,
    "week52Low": week52Low,
    "ytdChange": ytdChange,
    "lastTradeTime": lastTradeTime,
    "isUSMarketOpen": isUsMarketOpen,
  };
}
```

No error is generated, but no results either. 
[image]

> Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks the problem is `.expand((data) => (data as List))`, It looks that your API returns a JSON Object (Map) and not JSON Array (List)

Also I figured out another detail, "AAPL" is a key on JSON Object, which the value is another JSON Object, if you want to map its values to your `Class` you can use the expand to get the value of "AAPL" and pass it to your factory `fromJSON`

Other important thing, is to be sure that the keys that you are trying to map to your `Class` exists in JSON Object passed.
To avoid problems with dynamically keys (keys that maybe doesn't appear) you can use Null-aware Operator

> Null-aware operators in dart allow you to make computations based on whether or not a value is null. It’s shorthand for longer expressions.

An suggestion to make the things a little easy, maybe is don't use Streams for it, you can refactory your code for something async using only Future

```dart
const url = 'http://example.com/';
final response = await http.get(url);
final decodedResponse = json.decode(response);
final yourObject = Class.fromJSON(decodedResponse);
```

Last, but not least, I strongly recommend you to give a look on:

- https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16145788/5162053

Comment: Hello Helio thank you for your help. was able to fix based on your insights and comments, at the moment I have no error but no results either in the app. Any other ideas?