# How to convert JSON Object into Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array) and [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618548/convert-json-array-to-javascript-array), I would like to know how to do the exact same thing but with a different type of JSON :

Here my JSON Object :

```
var myDb = {
    "04c85ccab52880": {
        "name": "name1",
        "firstname": "fname1",
        "societe": "soc1"
    },
    "04c95ccab52880": {
        "name": "name2",
        "firstname": "fname2",
        "societe": "soc2"
    },
    "048574220e2a80": {
        "name": "name3",
        "firstname": "fname3",
        "societe": "soc3"
     }
};
```

My problem is that my JSON is different from their JSON, actually I have an array of array in mine. So how to convert this into a Javascript array ?

```
var arr = [];

$.each( myDb, function( key, value ) {
    arr.push( value );    
});

console.log(user_list);
```

This kind of script seems to return my 3 different objects but where are my uid from JSON ? How can I get them ? Because now my keys are 0,1,2 and no longer my uid.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/beXYZ/)

JS code:

```
//var arr = [];
var myDb = {
    "04c85ccab52880": {
        "name": "name1",
        "firstname": "fname1",
        "societe": "soc1"
    },
    "04c95ccab52880": {
        "name": "name2",
        "firstname": "fname2",
        "societe": "soc2"
    },
    "048574220e2a80": {
        "name": "name3",
        "firstname": "fname3",
        "societe": "soc3"
     }
};

$.each( myDb, function( key, value ) {
    //arr.push( value );    
    console.log("key => "+key);//will output: 04c85ccab52880 and all such
    $.each( value, function( ky, val ) {
        console.log('ky => '+ky);//will output: name, firstname, societe
        console.log('val => '+val);//will output: name1, fname1, soc1
    });    
});
```

Comment: It was a pleasure helping you FlorentP ! :)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert them, with key. I suggest something like below

```
var mapped = Object.keys( myDb  ).map(function( uid ){
    return (myDb[uid ].uid = uid ) && myDb[uid ];
});
```

for value in your array look like, example `mapped[0]` has value :

```
{
    "name": "name1",
    "firstname": "fname1",
    "societe": "soc1",
    "uid": "04c85ccab52880"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I specifically get the value of uid this way ? `mapped[0]` will return the whole object, but if I only need the uid for example ? Would `mapped[0]['uid']` work in your opinion ?