# dynamically feeding FB.ui properties

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

i feel like this should be really easy.  i am feeding the properties property of the FB.ui an array that contains json objects.  how can i loop through and output these objects with in the properties brackets?

this is the correct syntax:

`properties: [
{ text: 'value1', href: 'http://developers.facebook.com/'},
{ text: 'value1', href: 'http://developers.facebook.com/'}
]`

so far i can do this:
`properties: [
myArray[0],
myArray[1]
]`

and that outputs correctly, but what I want to do is dynamically output the array since it will often be a different size.  i have tried for in loops and regular for loops, but i can't use those inside these brackets.  probably a super easy answer, please help.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Maybe something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9fz2z/)?

Comment: i decided to reverse and create the json string and then use the jquery $.parseJSON() in the way described in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375537/convert-json-string-to-array-of-json-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), properties should be a JSON object and not an array.  Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
var myArray = [
    { text: 'value1', href: 'http://developers.facebook.com/'},
    { text: 'value2', href: 'http://developers.facebook.com/'}
];

var properties = {};
myArray.forEach(function(obj, index) {
    properties[index] = obj;
});
```

And then pass properties: properties in your call to FB.ui.