# How to convert a string to an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an input on a form which stores values as an object.

```
jQuery('#inputId').val()
```

returns something like

```
'[{"Id":"123","Name":"A","PathOfTerm":"A","Children":[],"Level":0,"RawTerm":null},{"Id":"234","Name":"B","PathOfTerm":"B","Children":[],"Level":0,"RawTerm":null}]'
```

as one single string. Is there any way to either prevent this from automatically converting to a string (maybe not using .val?) or to convert this from a string to something I could work with?

Comment: So you want to have it as a `object` ?

Comment: you could `JSON.parse` this

Comment: Looks like it's returning [JSON](http://www.json.org/). Lucky for you most browsers have the function [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert it to an object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON string to array of JSON objects in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375537/convert-json-string-to-array-of-json-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: It's not automatically converting to a string, form element values are always strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go

```
var array = JSON.parse(jQuery('#inputId').val());
```