# How to convert a JSON-like (not JSON) string to an object?

Tags: javascript, json

We all know we can use `JSON.parse()` to convert the string `'{"a":0,"b":"haha"}'` to the object `{a: 0, b: 'haha'}`.

But can we convert the string `'{a: 0, b: "haha"}'` to the object `{a: 0, b: 'haha'}`?

I'm writing a web crawler and I need to get the data in the page. But the complete data is not in DOM but in one `<script>` element. So I got the useful content in the `<script>` and converted that string (like `'window.Gbanners = [{...}, {...}, {...}, ...];'`) to a JSON-like string (like `'{banners : [...]}'`). However, I couldn't parse the "JSON-like" string. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JSON string to array of JSON objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375537/convert-json-string-to-array-of-json-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Dare I suggest `eval`? (and simply get rid of the first and last `'`)

Comment: Should we trust `eval`?

Comment: Are we fine with executing arbitrary code the scrapper might find on the internet?

Comment: @Kos No, we're not. I checked the script that I crawled and found it just did `window.Gbanners=[];`. Then I handled this script string simply and `eval`ed it. Maybe I'm fine with it temporarily？  -^_^-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
function evalJsString(str) {
    let a = null;
    try {
        eval('a = ' + str);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    if(typeof a === "object")
      return a;
    else
      return null;
}

evalJsString('({a: 0, b: "haha"})');
```

Comment: When I planed to try to use a recursive way to handle more complex string after seeing @kos's answer, this simple and cool solution surprised me a lot!

Answer (score 8):

A string like `{a: 0, b: "haha"}` is not JSON, but just a bunch of JavaScript code.

Best way to get a JSON representation of data inside is to run it through a JS parser (such as [Esprima](http://esprima.org/)), traverse the syntax tree and build a json object out of it. This needs some work, but at least you'll have the parsing done correctly, with proper handling of escape sequences.

Here's a starting point:

```
const esprima = require("esprima");
const code = '({a: 0, b: "haha"})';
const ast = esprima.parse(code);

const properties = ast.body[0].expression.properties;
const output = properties.reduce((result, property) => { 
  result[property.key.name] = property.value.value;
  return result;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

This code assumes a lot about what the input code looks like - might be OK for a prototype, but still needs error checking and handling nested objects.

(A more generic approach could involve a recursive function that takes an `ObjectExpression` and returns an equivalent JSON.)

I also had to wrap your input in parentheses so that it's an expression (not a block statement) according to JS grammar.

Comment: thanks! You mean I need to run the script in the `<script>`? Can you tell me about this more specifically? I'm using node.js.

Comment: No, you should just parse it, please don't run random scripts from the internet in your node environment :) Added example code to get you started

Answer (score 0):

As **eval()** has security flaws, it's better not to use it. A possible way would be creating a own parser to convert it to JSON string and then apply **JSON.parse()**. Something like below

```
function toJSONString(input) {
   const keyMatcher = '([^",{}\\s]+?)';
   const valMatcher = '(.,*)';
   const matcher = new RegExp(`${keyMatcher}\\s*:\\s*${valMatcher}`, 'g');
   const parser = (match, key, value) => `"${key}":${value}`
   return input.replace(matcher, parser);
}

JSON.parse(toJSONString('{a: 0, b: "haha"}'))
```